# Mysql - INSERT on TABLE 1 from SELECT on TABLE 2 with WHERE NOT EXIST on Table 1

Tags: mysql, insert, where-clause

Table1 has unique_id, ID_actor, ID_media, ID_program.

Each media may contain 1 or more programs, each programs may contain 1 or more actors and cannot be duplicated.

In another table (Table2) it has more info, sometimes in the title people record the name of the actor.. so i found this query to make the right reference to the media

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (ID_Actor,ID_Media,ID_Program) 
    (SELECT 123, ID_Media, ID_Program FROM TABLE2 WHERE Title LIKE '%ActorsName%')
```

This code works well but if already the actor was referenced to the program on the media, it will be duplicated.. so, since insert seems doesn't support WHERE don't know how to check first if the actor is already on table1, on that media and on that program comming from the SELECT query.

INSERT IF IS NOT PRESENT

```
    (SELECT ID_Actor,ID_Media,ID_Program from Table1 
WHERE ID_Actor = 123 
    AND ID_Media = (ID_media from SELECT QUERY) 
AND  ID_Program = (ID_Program From Select Query))
```

Comment: Lookup __INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE__. If you have a unique key on the columns that can't be duplicated, this should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd you missed the feature, since your question title has almost the exact syntax you need.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (ID_Actor,ID_Media,ID_Program) 
SELECT DISTINCT 123, t2.ID_Media, t2.ID_Program 
FROM TABLE2 AS t2
WHERE t2.Title LIKE '%ActorsName%'
   AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM Table1 AS t1
      WHERE t1.ID_Actor = 123
         AND t1.ID_Media = t2.ID_Media
         AND t1.ID_Program = t2.ID_Program
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason still adding new lines even if exsists.

Comment: Weird, the "AND NOT EXISTS" SELECT on table1 query display that exists an entry, but the INSERT query keeps adding a new row like the AND NOT EXISTS does not working

Comment: Try adding `DISTINCT` as I just did in my edit; the original query I provided would not prevent multiple rows inserted initially, just more of the same in later ones.

Comment: Do the tables, or their corresponding fields, have differing character collations? (... as I drop the assumption that the ID fields are integers).

Comment: Yes, are integers.

Comment: seem everything works well but not sure why the and not exists is not stoping the query.

Comment: Ok i found the error, a stupid one indeed.. the id actor was 1 number different than the inserted one.. Facepalm! Thanks for your help!